# can't see picture (jpg) after uploading in PHP

Tags: php, image, upload

My script uploads the selected pictures to a folder but in my other page I have to see it. But I can't see my uploaded picture.

But if I manually drag and drop the picture from the desktop to the folder then I can see the picture on the page.

This is my code where I want show the uploaded picture:

```
$image = "../images/accommodatie/".$row2['acco_id']."/";
$images = glob($image."*.jpg");
sort($images);
if (count($images) > 0) { 
    $img = $images[0];
    $img = str_replace("../","", $img); 
    echo "<a href='acco.php'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src='$img'>
        </div>";
}
```

I checked a few times, The folder location is correct, so that can not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing and closing double quote and a semi colon after your echo :

```
    if (count($images) > 0) { 

        $img = $images[0];
        $img = str_replace("../","", $img); 
        echo "<a href='acco.php'>
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src='$img'>
            </div>"; //<----- SEMI COLON HERE

    }
```

Comment: Not working, I forgot to place the semicolon, I fixed it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Then please put an error_reporting in your code so I can help you better

Comment: haha thats the problem, i got nothing of error code, It's empty

Comment: Really ? That's wierd ..did you added the following  ? :

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Really I got nothing, but I dropped 2 images in the image folder, 1 from my php script, and 1 from the desktop, when I load the page then I see only the picture that I've copied from the desktop . What the ?

Comment: Then try to var_dump you $img at every step of your script to see where it fails

Comment: I see the problem, but i can't fix it, please help.

Comment: $image = "../images/accommodatie/".$row2['acco_id']."/";
       $images = glob($image."*.jpg");  when i change the *.jpg to the picture name (01.jpg), then it shows the picture, but how can I pass this ??

Comment: but php thinks its empty, if i add else statement after if count > 0 and then an else statement with echo "couldnt find picture". And if i run the code, php is directly going to the else statement

Comment: Finally I FIXED It :D, i changed * *.jpg to *.* * You tried to help me, thanks !